# Is it possible to use aliases for pipeline parameters in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

Let's say I have the following parameters in my pipeline:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: environment
  displayName: 'Environment'
  default: 'SERVER_0562'
  type: string
  values: 
  - 'SERVER_0562'
  - 'SERVER_5149'
  - 'SERVER_1892'
```

But I don't want whoever is running the pipeline to see these names when selecting the `Environment` from the dropdown list. I want then to see the following names:

```
- QA Server
- DEV Server
- PROD Server
```

Is there any "easy" way to do so or the only way would be to deal with conditionals?

```yaml
${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'DEV Server') }}:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by the contribution of [@Krzysztof Madej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2347999/krzysztof-madej), I ended up solving my own issue by [conditionally assigning variables](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-assign-a-variable):

```yaml
parameters:
- name: environment
  displayName: 'Environment'
  default: 'QA Server'
  type: string
  values: 
  - 'QA Server'
  - 'DEV Server'
  - 'PROD Server'
  
trigger: none

variables:
  ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'QA Server') }}:
    bacon: SERVER_0562
  ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'DEV Server') }}:
    bacon: SERVER_5149
  ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'PROD Server') }}:
    bacon: SERVER_1892

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: build
  steps:
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with ${{ variables.bacon }}
```

I believe this is an easier implementation since I'm not dependent on a `PowerShell` script.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: image
  displayName: Pool Image
  type: string
  default: Ubuntu
  values:
  - Windows
  - Ubuntu
  - MacOS
  
trigger: none

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: build
  pool: 
    ${{ if eq(parameters.image, 'Ubuntu') }}:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    ${{ if eq(parameters.image, 'Windows') }}:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    ${{ if eq(parameters.image, 'MacOS') }}:
      vmImage: 'macOS-latest'
  steps:
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with ${{ parameters.image }}
```

After you changed a question I think this may help you

```yaml
parameters:
- name: environment
  displayName: 'Environment'
  default: 'QA Server'
  type: string
  values: 
  - 'QA Server'
  - 'DEV Server'
  - 'PROD Server'
  
trigger: none

variables:
- name: QA
  value: 'SERVER_0562'
- name: DEV
  value: 'SERVER_5149'
- name: PROD
  value: 'SERVER_1892'

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: build
  pool: 
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with ${{ parameters.environment }}
  - powershell: |
      
      If('${{ parameters.environment }}' -eq 'QA Server') {
        Write-Host '##vso[task.setvariable variable=folderName;isOutput=true]$(QA)'
      } ElseIf('${{ parameters.environment }}' -eq 'DEV Server') {
        Write-Host '##vso[task.setvariable variable=folderName;isOutput=true]$(DEV)'
      } ElseIf('${{ parameters.environment }}' -eq 'PROD Server') {
        Write-Host '##vso[task.setvariable variable=folderName;isOutput=true]$(PROD)'
      } Else {
        Write-Host 'I am here'
      }
    name: setFolderName
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host '$(setFolderName.folderName)'
```

Comment: The use of `vmImage` was just a sample senario, in my case to implement your solution I believe that I would have to use a custom variable, how can I do so in this case?

Comment: Sorry but if this sample is not your case, can you describe it? On example you used runtime parameters thus I presented this solution. Please detail you question so I can help you.

Comment: My bad, I should have been more specific in my sample, I just refactored it for better understanding.

Comment: @RogerioSchmitt Is `SERVER_0562` a name of your private pool?

Comment: Its a folder name I am using later to get some specif sever configs from another repository.

Comment: @KryztofMadej Thanks a lot for your contribution, based on your idea, I ended up solving my issue with the conditional assignment of variables, which I believe is an easier solution since in this way I'm not dependent on a `PowerShell` script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217548/discussion-between-rogerio-schmitt-and-krzysztof-madej).